# Originally wrong answer then morphed into correct after 30 mins

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

Does an originally wrong answer possibly turn into a correct one after 30 mins they wrote the original answer?

Chronologically:

1. He/she posted the wrong answer.
2. Then someone else answers with the correct one in a span of 5 minutes.
3. 25 Minutes later he/she revision the wrong answer into a correct one with more explanation then turned out to be accepted and voted more than the originally correct answer.

Previously I was flagging for a custom flag with "sure good, modifying your answer without attributing credits" then turn out got declined.

Is that really how it works?

Comment: Your flag message reads like a comment, not a flag. That's not how it works. Maybe the moderator declined your flag thinking you raised one by mistake when you meant to post a (rather snarky) comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> a correct one **with more explanation** then turned out to be accepted and voted more than the originally correct answer

Yes, this is how it works.

The answer should not get any benefit from its sordid history (luckily, most frequent visitors know to check the date/time of last edit and not only the creation), but if it now is the best answer and the best explanation, it will be rewarded completely apart from its history.

Now, if the answer is expounding on an earlier (earlier correct) answer, it should certainly give credit.  But that doesn't mean that the first correct/working answer with no/insufficient explanation will or should get the most votes.

Comment: I'm not sure about expounding earlier answer but it was a CSS oneliner issue. Which are rather obvious

Answer (score 6):

People won't go into the revisions and see. They just see if it is good, if it is up-vote it, otherwise down-vote it. It is as simple as that, and that's the same with the OP; the OP accepts the best one.

And yes, that's how it works. Of course, if the owner of the answer didn't edit, the other would be accepted. No matter what, your answer is good; it is good.

Comment: Let's take it in good faith then I assume.